# Limit of sequence of Lebesgue integrable functions is not Lebesgue integrable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Construct a sequence of functions $\{f_n(x)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset L([0,1])$ and measurable function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$ for all $x\in (0,1)$ and $$\left|\int_{(0,1)}f_n(x)d\mu\right|\leq 1$$ for all $n$, but $f(x)\notin L([0,1])$.

By $L([0,1])$ I mean Lebesgue integrable function on $[0,1]$.

I have spent some time trying to construct an example but I failed.

Would be very thankful for help!

Comment: Perhaps try a suitably scaled version of $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n {1 \over x} (-1)^k 1_{[{1 \over k+1},{1 \over k})}$.

Comment: Hint: if the condition were $\int |f_n|\,d\mu \le 1$ then Fatou's lemma would imply that $f$ would have to be integrable.  So you need functions $f_n$ for which $\int |f_n|$ is becoming large but $\left|\int f_n\right|$ is staying bounded, which can only happen if $f_n$ has large positive and negative parts whose integrals cancel.

Comment: @NateEldredge, Nice remark! I will think about this.

Comment: @NateEldredge, I got your hint. But I have troubles to construct such function :(

Comment: @ZFR: my answer contains an explicit construction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b_n := e^{-n}$, $n\in \mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$, and define
$$
f_n(x) := 
\begin{cases}
(-1)^j/x, & \text{if}\ b_{j+1} < x \leq b_j,\ j\leq n,\\
0, & \text{otherwise in}\ [0,1].
\end{cases}
$$
Since $\int_{b_{j+1}}^{b_j} f_n(x)\, dx = (-1)^j$, then
$|\int_0^1 f_n| = 1$. On the other hand, if $f$ is the pointwise limit of the sequence $(f_n)$, then $|f(x)| = 1/x$ for every $x\in (0,1]$.